# UIWebview is not closed

Tags: iphone

I am developing one application, in that I am using `UIWebview` and am opening the youtube on that webview.

I added close button for closing the webview, when i open the video on youtube and I click on close button, webview get closed but video sound is still playing.

So please tell me how can I remove the webview from my main view.

My close button code:

```
- (void)cancel:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
      [web stopLoading];
      [web removeFromSuperview];
      [cnclbtn removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this....It may solve your issue...

Before removing from super view just load that webview with empty html page like this...

```
- (void)cancel:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
  [web stopLoading];
  [web loadHTMLString:@"<html><head></head><body></body></html>" baseURL:nil];
  [web removeFromSuperview];
  [cnclbtn removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: Is there any solution based on concept.I written correctly.but why that webview respond like that.